# Word output based on NSString sequences

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

What I want to do is take 3 letter word sequences from an NSString, and change them in to corresponding words. EX) AUG = "START", AGC = "Asparagine", etc. My thought was to change the NSString in to an NSArray with each element containing 3 letters, where I can then reference them in a for loop, to make a new string with the Resulting words.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *aminoReplaceDict = @{
                                       @"AAA" : @"Lysine",
                                       @"AAC" : @"Asparagine",
                                       @"AAG" : @"Lysine",
                                       @"AAU" : @"Asparagine",
                                       @"ACA" : @"Threonine",
                                       @"ACC" : @"Threonine",
                                       @"ACG" : @"Threonine",
                                       @"ACU" : @"Threonine",
                                       @"AGA" : @"Arginine",
                                       @"AGC" : @"Serine",
                                       @"AGG" : @"Arginine",
                                       @"AGU" : @"Serine",
                                       @"AUA" : @"Isoleucine",
                                       @"AUC" : @"Isoleucine",
                                       @"AUG" : @"START",
                                       @"AUU" : @"Isoleucine",
                                       @"CAA" : @"Glutamine",
                                       @"CAC" : @"Histidine",
                                       @"CAG" : @"Glutamine",
                                       @"CAU" : @"Histidine",
                                       @"CCA" : @"Proline",
                                       @"CCC" : @"Proline",
                                       @"CCG" : @"Proline",
                                       @"CCU" : @"Proline",
                                       @"CGA" : @"Arginine",
                                       @"CGC" : @"Arginine",
                                       @"CGG" : @"Arginine",
                                       @"CGU" : @"Arginine",
                                       @"CUA" : @"Leucine",
                                       @"CUC" : @"Leucine",
                                       @"CUG" : @"Leucine",
                                       @"CUU" : @"Leucine",
                                       @"GAA" : @"Glutamic Acid",
                                       @"GAC" : @"Aspartic Acid",
                                       @"GAG" : @"Glutamic Acid",
                                       @"GAU" : @"Aspartic Acid",
                                       @"GCA" : @"Alanine",
                                       @"GCC" : @"Alanine",
                                       @"GCG" : @"Alanine",
                                       @"GCU" : @"Alanine",
                                       @"GGA" : @"Glycine",
                                       @"GGC" : @"Glycine",
                                       @"GGG" : @"Glycine",
                                       @"GGU" : @"Glycine",
                                       @"GUA" : @"Valine",
                                       @"GUC" : @"Valine",
                                       @"GUG" : @"Valine",
                                       @"GUU" : @"Valine",
                                       @"UAA" : @"STOP",
                                       @"UAC" : @"Tyrosine",
                                       @"UAG" : @"STOP",
                                       @"UAU" : @"Tyrosine",
                                       @"UCA" : @"Serine",
                                       @"UCC" : @"Serine",
                                       @"UCG" : @"Serine",
                                       @"UCU" : @"Serine",
                                       @"UGA" : @"STOP",
                                       @"UGC" : @"Cysteine",
                                       @"UGG" : @"Tryptonphan",
                                       @"UGU" : @"Cysteine",
                                       @"UUA" : @"Leucine",
                                       @"UUC" : @"Phenylalanine",
                                       @"UUG" : @"START",
                                       @"UUU" : @"Phenylalanine",
                                       };
    NSMutableString *replaceString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:_trnaOut.text];
    for( NSString *replaceWord in [aminoReplaceDict allKeys] )
    {
        [replaceString replaceOccurrencesOfString:replaceWord withString:aminoReplaceDict[replaceWord] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, replaceString.length )];
    }
    _aminoOut.text = replaceString;
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Have I misunderstood your question? You seem to want to convert, for example, "AUC" to "Word 1" yet the currently accepted answer is doing the reverse and doesn't deal with overlaps (e.g. "AUCAUC" contains "UCA" but is not a valid codon match for that string).

Comment: @CRD I accepted the answer because I easily reversed it and it works, however, I just realized that there is an over lapping problem as I have just commented on my accepted answer, and updated in my code.

Comment: Problems were fixed and code was updated in the accepted answer.

Comment: Good to know I wasn't going cross-eyed, and that you've figured the overlapping issue (BTW in the current version of the answer you can combine the two loops into one).

Comment: @CRD Would you mind editing to reflect the single loop?

Comment: The first loop converts your string into an array of 3 letter strings, the second converts this array into another array taking each 3 letter string and converting it to a string found by looking up in a dictionary. That intermediate array clearly isn't needed, just do it in one loop. You also need to check the input is an exact multiple of 3 and if not deal with that case (error, discard extra 1 or 2 chars, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (leaving out the dictionary which is the same in your question):

```
 NSString *exampleString = @"AAACAACAU";
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( int i = 0; i < exampleString.length; i += 3)
{
    NSString *substring = [exampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 3)];
    [stringArray addObject:substring];
}

NSMutableArray *replacedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( NSString *key in stringArray)
{
    NSString *replacedWord = aminoReplaceDict[key];
    [replacedArray addObject:replacedWord];
}

NSString *replaceString = [replacedArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"%@", replaceString);
```

Comment: Where do I put the string that is to be used for replacement?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: The original NSString that is @"AUCGUAUCA", where do I reference that NSString in that code?

Comment: You don't need to split the string because you are setting up the replacement relationships in the NSDictionary.

Comment: @jonah, you are passing invalid object to mutablestring please correct it

Comment: @hussainShabbir I copied and pasted my solution from a working test project. You are incorrect sir. Here is the output from the log statement:  2013-10-14 10:12:28.317 TestProj[79357:a0b] AUG, GUA, UCA

Comment: I understand that, but the dictionary needs a string to be able to make necessary replacements right? Where in the code is that string called?

Comment: But you have not mentioned @"" symbol in mutable string for last two words

Comment: @RileyLloyd The string being modified is the mutable string replaceString. Notice how in the loop we are replacing the occurrences of the dictionary keys with the dictionary words?

Comment: @hussainShabbir I am not sure what you are talking about. @"" is an empty string.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I thought you were using an external string for the replacement. I now see that "replaceString" was the string being replaced in the code.

Comment: I am talking about this line NSMutableString *replaceString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Word 1, Word 2, Word 3"];
for( NSString *replaceWord in [replaceDict allKeys] ) in this word2 and word3. It should be like this @"Word2" @Word3" right??

Comment: @hussainShabbir Nope. You are incorrect. If you copy and paste my answer into a solution you will see that it works. Also, you can clearly see the spaces between the "Word" and the number, i.e. @"Word 1".

Comment: @hussainShabbir Jonah is right. The string you are referring to is what is being replaced. It doesn't need to be separate strings, it works perfectly being one big string.

Comment: @RileyLloyd Glad you were able to figure it out. Let me know if you have any more questions. hussainShabbir, move along, these are not the droids you are looking for.

Comment: @Jonah.at.GoDaddy hahahah, I love StarWars, you made my day!

Comment: @Jonah.at.GoDaddy One more problem. You were going from words to letter triplets, I reversed it. But the thing is, its not going in order, it is skipping letters, see edited code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39207/discussion-between-jonah-at-godaddy-and-riley-lloyd)

Answer (score 1):

@riley Lloyd, As i understand your requirement below:-

```
First you need to split your string into three characters:-
NSString *yourString = @"AUCGUAUCA";

//it will give you AUC
NSRange oneToThreeRange= NSMakeRange(0, 3);
NSString *oneToThree= [yourString substringWithRange:oneToThreeRange];


//it will give you GUA
NSRange fourToSixRange= NSMakeRange(3, 3);
NSString *fourToSix= [yourString substringWithRange:fourToSixRange];

//it will give you UCA
NSRange sixToNineRange= NSMakeRange(6, 3);
NSString *sixToNine= [yourString substringWithRange:sixToNineRange];

//Now add on your array and perform what you want to do

NSArray * youArr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:oneToThree,fourToSix,sixToNine,nil];
NSLog(@"%@",youArr);
```

Comment: You are over complicating the problem. There is no need to do all this substring stuff as you can set it up much easier in a dictionary.

Comment: Also, since the string is inputed by a user, there is no telling how many of these you'd have to make. It is not practical.

Comment: Ohk i thought you wanted your string to break first. Its fine the above code will be helpful when any one wanted to split the string in above situation.