# i want to this string array arrange in key value form like hashmap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6.1

`("1$Indore","2$Lyallpur","3$Sagan","4$Bhopal","5$Reva","6$Santa","7$Dar","8$Chinaware","9$Gwalior","10$Jain","11$Morena","12$West Nimar","13$Chatterer")`

I want to this string array arrange in key value form like hash map from the "$" and select value like Indore in `UIPicker` and result in its key like 1. pl z help me...  but plz more justify because this string fetch from server i cant write self use in my code key is 1 and value is Indore.

Comment: m just giving you the idea logic is upto you:- you can use for loop and inside that separate the strings with $ and store two values into different arrays then you'll be able to have access on whatever value you want.

Comment: use NSDictionary for key value pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NSDictionary` can be used as a hash map and the syntax is very simple. A `NSDictionary` literal is declared using `@{ }` and can contain a comma-seperated list of key-value pairs. These key-value pairs are declared as `key: value`.

For example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"1": @"Indore", @"2":@"Lyallpur", ... };
```

**EDIT:** To convert the string array (let's call it *values*) in the original question to a NSDictionary, you'd do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *value in values) {
    NSArray *keyValuePair = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];

    [dict setObject:keyValuePair[1] forKey:keyValuePair[0]];
}
```

Comment: thanks but plz more justify because this string from server i cant self use in my code

Comment: @AbhishekMaheshwari I've updated my answer. I'm assuming the data you posted is an _array of strings_ rather than a _string_.

Comment: ok its inside that separate the strings with $ and store but how to two values into different arrays then i'll be able to have access on whatever value i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this NSDictionary below:-

```
//Add how many elements you want to add on your array
    NSDictionary *yourDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"$Indore", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil]];
    NSString *yourStr=[yourDict objectForKey:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"%@",yourStr);
```

Comment: thanks but plz more justify because this string from server i cant self use in my code

Comment: oh ok then follow this link here you will get idea how to split string from server. Please follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364787/word-output-based-on-nsstring-sequences/19365935#19365935